# Tab with UITableView takes long to load

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a tab that contains a UITableView. The UITableView loads JSON from a server. Here are some lines in my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
// Register the UITableViewCell class with the tableView
        self.tableView?.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellIdentifier)
        var tblView =  UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
        tableView.tableFooterView = tblView
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        startConnection()
```

Here is my `startConnection()`:

```
func startConnection() {
        let url = NSURL(string: "some correct URL")
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
        if data != nil {
            var json = JSON(data: data!)

            if let jsonArray = json.arrayValue {
                for jsonDict in jsonArray {
                    var pageName: String? = jsonDict["title"].stringValue

                    //some code

                }
            }
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        } else {
            println("No data")
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "No data", message: "No data received", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in

            }
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)

            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .Default) { (action) in
                self.startConnection()
            }
            alert.addAction(OKAction)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

After the first load, the tab will show upon clicking. I am thinking if it is the `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest` causing the lag. Any advice and suggestion? I don't really know how to use sendAsynchronousRequest either =/ Please help. Thank you! =D

Comment: Yes, downloading data synchronously is causing this. Download it asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are several ways to get data from a website, the important thing is that you execute your UI updates on the main thread using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {}`. This is because URL tasks such as `NSURLSession.dataTaskWithURL` or `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest() {}` execute on a background thread so if you don't explicitly update UI on the main thread you will often experience a lag. Here's what a simple request looks like:

```
func fetchJSON(sender: AnyObject?) {

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "www.someurl.com")

    session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error)  in

        var rawJSON: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .allZeros, error: nil)

        if let result = rawJSON as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                // Update your UI here ie. tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"some url")
let request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    /* Your code */
})
```

Comment: I believe yours will work as well, but I tried the answer that was given first. Since the problem was really me loading data in the main thread, doing it asynchronously using your method should work as well. Thank you!